# Is there a shorthand equivalent for the double pipe operator which treats empty strings as falsy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, it's common to use the double pipe operator to test if a variable is falsy and to apply some kind of default setting when variables are undefined. Here's a line of config I just came across in a codebase I'm doing some work on:

```
config.uh_product_name = ENV['UH_PRODUCT_NAME'] || 'Unicorn Hunt'
```

This is all well and good if `ENV["UH_PRODUCT_NAME"]` is `nil`. But in this case, because of the way the .env file is set by default, `ENV["UH_PRODUCT_NAME"]` is an empty string `""`, which is truthy. So the default is not applied.

I could do this to handle this case:

```
config.uh_product_name = ENV['UH_PRODUCT_NAME'].present? ? 'Unicorn Hunt' : ENV['UH_PRODUCT_NAME']
```

But that's much less readable and ends up with a line of code that potentially stretches off screen.

So, does anyone know of a shorthand operator along the lines of `||` that applies Rails's `.blank?` or treats empty strings as falsy? Something like this perhaps:

```
config.uh_product_name = ENV['UH_PRODUCT_NAME'] ?|| 'Unicorn Hunt'
```

Comment: _"because of the way the .env file is set by default"_ – what do you mean? Why is `ENV["UH_PRODUCT_NAME"]` an empty string in the first place?

Comment: @stefan it's a generic env file that has a bunch of blank lines in it. I'm more interested in the overall issue than the specific. I realise I can add lines in the .env file, but I've often come up against similar and thought it would be a good question for SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the "nullifier" [Object#presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#presence):

```
config.uh_product_name = ENV['UH_PRODUCT_NAME'].presence || 'Unicorn Hunt'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is looking like a strong contender! I've just been reading into whether it's possible to override operators and it looks hard to impossible.

Comment: yeah `#presence` is nice one in this case.

Comment: Having just tried this, nil.presence throws a nomethod error, presumably because of load order for config files. Investigating... :/

Comment: @stef What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @stef I'd try loading the module, i.e. `require 'active_support/core_ext/object'`

Comment: @tokland yep. Just a bit wary given past load order issues. Anyway - details. Thanks for this suggestion.